# Disable all notification programmatically

Tags: android, android-notifications

In my app I need to disable all the notifications for the other applications existing that appear when the lockscreen is activated.

My APP turn in android 4.4 min and 6 max.

Thank's for you're help.

Comment: Of your app or other apps?  Your app may be possible, other apps is not.

Comment: Ok, and it's possible When one click on the notification that it launches my application directly and not the application of the notification?
Or while my application to create a personalized lockscreen? And it's not possible my app blocked the other app notification?

Comment: No, its not possible to hijack a notification like that.  It would be a huge security risk, a malware app could take over a notification from my bank.  As for a custom lock screen-  that used to be possible, I don't believe it is anymore.

Comment: Thank's you, I have create personnal lock screen and it turn perfectly